# What hardware specs is needed for IPython?

Tags: python, linux, ipython

I would like to setup an IPython Linux server for 50 students, so each gets their own instance. However I can't find any server hardware specs.

**Question**

- How much memory and CPU is required for 50 instances?
- How much memory and CPU is required for 100 instances?

Comment: Off-topic hereabouts.

Answer (score 1):

There is no multiuser support provided by ipython yet. Also same questions has been shared below too

http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/IPython-User-Advice-on-running-a-server-with-multiple-users-td4986372.html

Hope it might give some overview

Comment: I can't see they give any hardware specs. Do they?

Comment: 256 Mb - 2 GB might be needed based on heavy/light requirements of the project. In most case 512 MB - 1 GB will be standard one to use

Ref:
https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/3406

Comment: That is client side. I am asking about server side.